# Store Two query response in to one variable

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add a In Memory Caching to my .NET core project that uses EF. I have two queries and want that two query response to be stored in Cache so I dont have to query everytime

```
var settingscheck = "SELECT TOP 1 [EndTime],[StartTime],[OrderDay]"+
                                 "FROM[dbo].[Settings]"+
                                  "where SUBSTRING(DATENAME(weekday, getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'), 0, 4) = OrderDay";

var holidaycheck = "SELECT Count(*) FROM[dbo].[HolidayWeeks] where FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') = [HolidateDate]";
```

I already implemented the Caching to store one of the Query response like below

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString,
                                       int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
  {
    int holidaycheck;
    var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    var todayDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);

    bool isExist = memoryCache.TryGetValue("HolidayWk", out holidaycheck);
    if (!isExist)
    {
        holidaycheck = (from hc in _context.HolidayWeeks
                        where hc.HolidateDate.Date == todayDt.Date
                        select hc).Count();
        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

        memoryCache.Set("HolidayWk", holidaycheck, cacheEntryOptions);
    }

    if (holidaycheck != 0)
    {
        return View("/Views/Customers/AppNotAvailable.cshtml");
    }
    else
    {
```

but now I am trying to add one more query, I was thinking if I can create the JSON object and add the response from both the queries and cache them in memory so it can be used by the application. I cannot do JOIN because these two queries dont have anything in common I am not sure how to store the response from both the queries in to one JSON object. Or suggest me if there is any other option of doing this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Side points: `SUBSTRING` begins at `1` not `0`. And `CAST(... AS date)` is more efficient (and more correct) than `FORMAT(..., 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for that input.. The OrderDay field stores the three letter char that shows the day like MON,TUE I need that field to compare against today's day.. Do you think CAST(as datae) will work for that comparison

Comment: @Charlieface Can you please also suggest me with the store data in to JSON

Comment: No it wouldn't work, I was referring rather to the `HolidateDate` check. Unclear what your issue is: why can;t you store them in separate `memoryCache` keys?

Comment: @Charlieface Can we have multiple Cache keys in the same project?

Comment: @Charlieface I am sorry I am still unclear about the Query suggestion. I am new this Programming any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I think so. Just do `memoryCache.Set("settings", settingsResult, cacheEntryOptions);`. Your second query can be improved: `SELECT Count(*) FROM[dbo].[HolidayWeeks] where CAST(getdate() AS date) = [HolidateDate]`

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you !!! I have replaced that query as the linq query like `from hc in _context.HolidayWeeks
                        where hc.HolidateDate.Date == todayDt.Date
                        select hc` You think this is fine?

Comment: No, why `hc.HolidateDate.Date` just use `hc.HolidateDate`. If it might have a date component then use a date range `where hc.HolidateDate >= todayDt.Date && hc.HolidateDate < todayDt.Date.AddDays(1)`

Comment: Ok thanks I will do that